# moved a file in second folder that already have a file with same name. File is not shown in second folder

Tags: linux

I had made two folders with names, AFolder and BFolder. I had created a file "sample.txt" using `touch` command in AFolder. I copied "sample.txt" from AFolder to BFolder. Then I moved the text files from BFolder to AFolder, But the "sample.txt" not found in AFolder.

where is my text file that I moved to AFolder?

**Commands**

```
mkdir AFolder
mkdir BFolder
cd AFolder
touch sample.txt
cp sample.txt /home/kali/Desktop/BFolder
cd ..
cd BFolder
ls
mv sample.txt /home/kali/Desktop/AFolder
cd ..
cd AFolder
ls
```

here only a single file (sample.txt) is listed, that i had created, but where is another sample.txt file that i had moved to this folder ?

Thank You.
I am using Kali Linux.

Comment: Did you intend to mv sample.text rather than sample.txt?  If so, it's likely mv produced an error you may not have noticed. Also, are you sure you started in '/home/kali/Desktop'?

Comment: no, its not .text, i wrote it mistakenly on this website. there is sample.txt

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand. Did you move sample.txt from BFolder to AFolder, or did you move sample.text? If what's showing in the command list is wrong, please edit the question and correct the typo.

Comment: What exactly did you expect to happen? If directories `AFolder` and `BFolder` both contain file named `sample.txt` and you `mv BFolder/sample.txt AFolder/`, the file with the same name in `AFolder` will be overwritten. `AFolder` will contain one file - you can't have two files with the same name in the same directory. `BFolder` will be empty.

Comment: @Peregrino69 your information is true, I understood what happened to the file. It got replaced. Thankyou.

Comment: Please accept my answer so the question doesn't keep popping up as "Unanswered" in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have two files with the same name in the same directory.

If you already have a file named 'sample.txt' in directory `AFolder` and you move into it a file with the same name from another folder, the new file will overwrite the existing one. If you want to keep both files, one of them has to be renamed.